# Select2 loses focus when typing a new tag

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I am trying to use Select2 to let users select and create tags. But creating a new tag does not work as expected as after typing two letters, the input loses focus.

This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046676/select2-cant-create-new-options-longer-than-2-characters-tag-true) relates the exact same problem apparently, but mine does not get fixed with the new versions of Select2 or Jquery.

Here is the code:

```
-  content_for :scripts do
  :javascript
    const input = document.querySelector('#input-tags');
    $("#input-tags").select2({
      tags: true,
      tokenSeparators: [','],
    });

  = f.input :code_list,  input_html: {id: 'input-tags', multiple: 'multiple'}, collection: @entry.code_list
```

Jquery: "jquery": "^3.5.1"
Select2: "select2": "^4.0.13'

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem as you, and a solved when updated to version 4.1.0.